# Django Migrations in CI/CD pipeline

Tags: django, docker, database-migration, django-migrations, cicd

My CI/CD pipeline is triggered whenever there is a code push. There is an already populated database(PostgreSQL). I am doing changes in models.py (specifically adding a new model) and `python manage.py makemigrations <app-name>` and `python manage.py migrate` commands are written in docker entry-point file, so I expect that on every code push, these commands will execute and create migrations file and database should reflect changes. But database isn't showing any changes at all, however, Django's admin page is showing the new model name.

Also, **there is no migrations folder present in the repository** at all in any app. How do i resolve it. I wanna add a new table and add a new column in an existing table

Comment: Don't run `makemigrations` in your entrypoint, you should run them manually after you make changes to your models and commit the migration files to your repository

Comment: @IainShelvington actually, my repository doesnt have migrations folder at all and database has been populated already

Comment: Then you have a bit of an issue since you have no record of which changes have been made to any of your databases. Can you run `python manage.py showmigrations <app-name> -v 3` on a deployed instance and share the output? Should show when the last migration was applied

Comment: Ideally you should put the migration file in git so that django will not be confused which migration to run and what is the order.

Comment: @adshin21 The code is in Prod environment and the repository doesn't have migrations folder. Postgres does have django_migrations table to keep a track of all previously applied migrations. I just want to update a model so that changes reflect in postgres